# Sprinkler pipe in concrete

Tags: concrete, pvc, sprinkler-system

I'm having a concrete deck installed, and I'm keeping a sprinkler pipe in the concrete for use in a drip system.  Is it ok if the pipe is PVC or should I replace it with a galvanized pipe?

Comment: More information, please. What's a concrete deck? Do you mean a patio? Why is the pipe in the concrete? Where in the world are you? It's hard to help with so few words telling us about your project. Please revise your post to add detail.

Comment: Galvanized has bad habit of rusting out in thirty or forty years or less.  Doubt if you will want to break concrete then.   Metal pipes also can burst if frozen from cold weather.  Plastic is a bit more forgiving.

Comment: I prefer metal coming out of a slab because a slight bump on pvc and it is broken.I don’t think I can remember seeing pvc or nm conduit coming out of concrete that was not cracked or broken in just a few years so I would be good with 30-40years So with one thinking over is good and one galvanized this would be an opinion question and those are off topic.